# Use of capturing group in .split() function

Tags: javascript, regex, split, regex-negation, capturing-group

I have a string and i want to split it into array using the '|' character but not '\|':

```
var a = 'abc\&|\|cba';
var b = a.split(/([^\\])\|/);
```

result :

```
b = ["abc", "&", "|cba"]
```

expected output :

```
b = ["abc\&", "\|cba"]
```

Basically I cannot use capturing groups in .split() function properly.

Comment: Just to clarify: you have `var a = 'abc\\&|\\|cba';` (=`abc\&|\|cba`) or really `var a = 'abc\&|\|cba';` (=`abc&||cba`)? Also, you do not need a capturing group here, you need a lookbehind, but since it is missing in JS regex flavor, you need to *match* the strings you require.

Comment: Try [`b = a.match(/(?:[^\\|]|\\.)+/g)`](https://jsfiddle.net/r97opth9/)

Comment: If you need to separate the extracted words using "|" do you intentionally need only the split words beginning with alphabets like `["abc\&", "cba"]`? or else your array will be split as follows according to your string variable a -> `["abc\&", "\", "cba"]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - i have 'abc\&|\|cba that is single escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead for splitting.

With escaped backslash

```js
var a = 'abc\\&|\\|cba';
var b = a.split(/\|(?=\\)/);
console.log(b);
```

Without escaped backslash

**`/\|(?=\|)/`**

- `\|` matches the character `|` literally
- `(?=\|)` **Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched**

  - `\|` matches the character `|` literally

Basically it looks for a pipe, and splits if another pipe is following.

```js
var a = 'abc\&|\|cba';
var b = a.split(/\|(?=\|)/);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I do not think it is what OP needs (splitting with the non-escaped pipe)

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Can you please explain your second solution? @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using regex expressions, storing each identified word( in this case the price) in an array and then grabbing it when needed

```
var re = /(?:^|[ ])|([a-zA-Z]+)/gm;
var str = 'abc\&|\|cba';
var identifiedWords;

while ((identifiedWords = re.exec(str)) != null) 
{
    if (identifiedWords.index === re.lastIndex) 
    {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
// View your result using the "identifiedWords" variable.
// eg identifiedWords[0] = abc\&
// identifiedWords[1] = cba
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a literal `\` in your strings, and that your question contains a typo in the input string literal. In JS C strings, you need to use a double `\` to define a literal backslash (since in regular string literals, you can define escape sequences like `\r`, `\n`, etc).

Your regex needs to match all characters other than `\` and `|` or any literal `\` followed with any letter. If your string can equal a literal `\`, you need

```js
var a = 'abc\\&|\\|cba';
b = a.match(/(?:[^\\|]|\\.?)+/g);
console.log(b);
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` - (start of a non-capturing alternation group)

  - `[^\\|]` - any char other than `\` and `|`
  - `|` - or
  - `\\.?` - a `\` followed with any 1 or 0 chars but a newline
- `)+` - 1 or more times

Comment: But I actually have single escaping and not double escaping. I'm afraid can't it be done? :(

Comment: No, this is not possible, because you either have them as literal symbols, or you have none.